# expo react native : 'undefined is not an object' (evaluating RCTWEBVIEW BRIDGEManager.NavigationType)

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, exp

I could not find JAVA files to do the configurations for android and gives the error 'undefined is not an object' (evaluating RCTWEBVIEW BRIDGEManager.NavigationType) when I try to execute the following in the project that expo XDE created

my code is as follows

```
  import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, WebView } from 'react-native';
import WebViewBridge from 'react-native-webview-bridge';


export default class testWebBridge extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.handleMessage = this.handleMessage.bind(this) // <----- add this line       
    }
    handleMessage(e) {
            console.log("[native] receive a msg" + e.nativeEvent.data);
            if (this.webview) {
                    this.webview.postMessage("[native] received the message");
            }

    }

    render() {
            return (
                    <WebView
                       javaScriptEnabled
                       ref={webview => { this.webview = webview; }}
                       source={{uri: 'https://www.customapps.co.nz/home'}}
                       onMessage={this.handleMessage}
                       style={{marginTop: 40}}
                     />
             );
    }
}
```